# Python - "Module could not be loaded" error while trying to activate a virtual environment

Tags: python

While trying to activate a virtual environment called "dat1triviabot_env" on Windows, I get this error:
`dat1triviabot-env\Scripts\activate.bat: The module 'dat1triviabot-env' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module dat1triviabot-env'.`

I have the `virtualenv` package installed, version `20.16.2`, and I used the command `python3 -m venv dat1triviabot-env` to create the virtual environment.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you running this from Powershell, Command Prompt, or Git CLI?

Comment: @gman I'm using Powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in PowerShell, try just running `dat1triviabot-env/Scripts/activate`.